# EF Where after AsEnumerable - do all the entries from the query are loaded in memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I have such code in Entity Framework
`var data = query.AsEnumerable().Where(x => IsObjectValid(x)).ToList()`
where *query* is IQueryable that can be translated to SQL.

Will Entity Framework load **all** the entries from the database in-memory (just as ToList() would do) and then apply the *IsObjectValid()* function and filter the data.
Or Entity Framework will load entries from the database **one by one** and apply the filtration function?

If I have 1000 entries in query, where each weighs 1 MB, will the memory usage be the same for ToList().Where() and for AsEnumerable().Where()?

In my tests .AsEnumerable() worked faster and consumed way less memory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part before `AsEnumerable()` will be translated to SQL and performed by the DB. The part after `AsEnumerable()` will be performed as LINQ to Objects after the data has been loaded from the DB.

```
var data = dbContext.Data
    .Where(d => d.Author = "me")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(d => MyCustomValidationFunction(d))
    .ToList();
```

The first `Where` will be performed on the DB and only the records with `Author = "me"` will be returned to your application. The second `Where` will then be performed on this returned data and the `ToList()` on the data filtered twice.

Custom functions cannot be translated to SQL. Therefore, `AsEnumerable()` is required to be able to call this function locally. But it is advisable to do as much of a filtering and grouping, etc. before `AsEnumerable()` to minimize the returned data.

The first `Where` expects an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` parameter, where as the second one expects a `Func<T, bool>` parameter. I.e., `AsEnumerable()` transitions from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

An `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` consists of a data structure representing the syntax of the lambda function. This syntax is translated to an equivalent SQL syntax. This also means that the lambda expressions used in IQueryables are actually never executed. Therefore, it does not matter whether you write e.g. `Where(x => hasSet.Contains(x))` or `Where(x => array.Contains(x))` performance-wise. Both will be translated to something like `WHERE x IN (a, b, c)`. But it matters after `AsEnumerable()`. `HashSet<T>.Contains` is faster than `List<T>.Contains` or `T[].Contains`.

As @DavidBrowne-Microsoft explains, `AsEnumerable()` does a [lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/15/c-ienumerable-yield-return-and-lazy-evaluation/) over a `DataReader`. The following LINQ to Objects operations perform a lazy evaluation whenever possible. I.e., one data object is processed at a time and passed over to the next operation.

Operations like `Where`, `Select`, `Skip`, `SkipWhile` etc, perform a lazy evaluation. Other operations like `OrderBy`, `GroupBy` or `Reverse` must keep all the data in memory.

And of course `ToList`, `ToArray` and `ToDictionary` pull all the data and store it in memory. I often see people append a `ToList()` to a query just to do a `for` or `foreach` on the result. Perform the `foreach` directly on the `IEnumerable<T>` result whenever possible! Often there is no need to store the whole data in memory.

Comment: I understand, but the question is: if Where() is being called after AsEnumerable(), the full data is loaded in-memory or data entries are loaded in memory one by one? 
It is important, because if I have a lot of data entries after db filtration, I may not want all the data to be put in memory at one time.

Comment: AsEnumerble returns an IEnumerble over the DataReader.  Entities are streamed one-by-one through the second predicate, and only the entities matching the second Where() are kept in memory.  Assuming change tracking is disabled, all non-matching entities become eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks! It's what I was looking for! Can you convert this to the answer?
Also, what SQL is being generated? How is the data selected from the database, but not loaded into memory instantly? Are there articles I can dig deeper into?